# How can I use a filter inside a filter argument?

Tags: angular

I have a date and I want to apply a format depends on the language so I want to get the string that contains the format and use it as a parameter for the date formatting. But it says me that the expression hasn't a valid syntax, how can do that ?

```
Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 46 of the expression [resultsDate | date:{{'date.format' | translate] starting at [{'date.format' | translate].

{{ resultsDate | date:{{'date.format' | translate }}  }}
```

Comment: Could you share us the code you are working with? It's a bit hard to figure out what's wrong on your code this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if `'date.format' | translate` is the right way to adjust the localization of the date format. In fact, the Angular `date` pipe accepts a `locale` parameter. See [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#description) to apply the `locale` parameter.

That said, you could wrap the first pipe in a `<ng-container>` with a `*ngIf` and leverage it's `as` construct to "create" a local variable. The `<ng-container>` tags wouldn't contribute to additional elements and would be commented out in the rendered DOM.

Try the following

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(date.format | translate) as translatedFormat">
  {{ resultsDate | date:translatedFormat }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: yes, I will think about change date pipe thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
{{ resultsDate | date: 'translateValue' }}
```

Inside resultsDate pipe handle parameter translateValue.